# Getting access to the state of a node in NxN 2D array

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm implementing NxN puzzle in 2D array in Java.  I have the following classes:

```
public class Node {

    //private members
    private int boardSize;
    private int row, col;

    int state[][] = new int[][]{};   //the state of a node

    // the total cost from root node to current node
    private int pathCost;  
    // this is the heuristic cost from the current node to the goal node
    private int heuristicCost;  
   // functionCost = pathCost + heuristicCost
    private int funcitonCost; 
    // parent of the current node
    private Node parentNode;

   ......

  // I have here all accessor functions and functions that return x and y cordinates when a //number in the array is given.
}

public class A*Algo {



    private int[][] goalNode ={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,0}};

    private NodeComparator nodeComparator = new NodeComparator();
    private PriorityQueue<Node> openList = null;    // open list
    private PriorityQueue<Node> closedList = null;       // closed list
    private int steps = 0;
    private int BOARDSIZE;


          // constructor
          public AStar(Node startNode, int boardSize){
        //this.node = new Node(tiles, null, boardSize);
        //this.tiles = tiles;
        this.BOARDSIZE = boardSize;
    /*  this.succesorNodes = new FifoNodeStore();
        this.fringeNodes = new FifoNodeStore();*/
        this.openList = new PriorityQueue<Node>(0, nodeComparator);
        this.closedList = new PriorityQueue<Node>(0, nodeComparator);

        startNode.setParentNode(null);
        startNode.setPathCost(0);
                // PROBLEM :::: goalNode must be a Node and not int[][]
                // How can i represent the goal node?
        startNode.setHeuristicCost(manhattan(startNode, goalNode)); 
        this.addToOpenList(startNode);
        this.search(startNode);
    }



   public int manhattan(Node currentNode, Node goalNode) {
    return Math.abs(currentNode.x - goalNode.x) + Math.abs(currentNode.y - goalNode.y);
    }

}
```

I have the following two problems:

1)
How should I represent the goal Node?
In the second class I declare the goal node as `int[][]` but I want it to be a node so that I can give it to the manhattan function.

2)
In the Node class, I have a state `int state[][]` which represent the state of the node. Now my problem is how do i get access to the individual coordinates in the state in the nodes.  Assuming the goalNode declaration is correct then I must be able to call the manhattan like this:

```
manhattan(startNode, goalNode)
```

to calculate from the current node to the goal node.

### Edit

I am required to use the manhattan heuristic in the following way:

```
the sum of the vertical and horizontal distances from 
            the current node to the goal node/tile

                            +(plus)

the number of moves to reach the goal node from the initial position
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can represent the goal node as `Node goalNode`. You can have a constructor/function/property in you Node class to set the state of the node. 
something like this:

```
public class Node {

    //private members
    private int boardSize;
    private int row, col;

    int state[][] = new int[][]{};   //the state of a node

    public Node(int[][] nodeState)
    {
         state=nodeState;
    } 

    ........
}
```

2) If I understand you correctly you are looking for something like this:

```
public int Manhattan(Node current Node goal){
    int dist = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < current.row; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < current.col; y++)
            dist += Math.abs(current.state[x][y] - goal.state[x][y]);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, i have edited my post now with the requirement of the manhattan heureustic. Normally i have to calculate the manhattan for each node to the goal node so that i can know which node is better than than the other in order to have the optimal path.

Comment: I think soooooooooooooooooo. You are genius. I have some few questions in order to understand your code. int state[][] is the state of the node. Now if you do state[x], what value do you get? I just want to understand your code

Comment: see my second edit. it should be Node[x][y]. that will give you some int.

Comment: I think what you did first was right. We have to calculate the distance but now you are using the real values in the tiles instead of the distance of one tile from the other

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5235/discussion-between-eddy-freeman-and-aliza)